# Eclipse WTP: "The import ___ cannot be resolved for" error in a JSP file for a class defined in project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, weblogic, eclipse-wtp

A Visual Studio user struggling w/ Eclipse...

I imported a set of servlets/JSPs into a project in Oracle Workshop for Weblogic.  /page.jsp  has the following import statement:

```
import="com.foo.bar.*"
```

Eclipse is displaying an error:

> The import com cannot be resolved.

The class that implements the above import is in `/WEB-INF/src` but I don't know how to build the class in Eclipse to resolve that error.  I assumed Eclipse would automagically build the `.java` file and place the output in `/WEB-INF/classes`, but it's not doing that.

It could be that I haven't structured my project directories correctly so perhaps that's why Eclipse isn't building my source. Any suggestions?  How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, `/WEB-INF/src` is a rather strange place to keep your java sources; you may want to move them out of `/WEB-INF` (into `/src` in project root, for example)

Either way, you need to tell Eclipse where your sources are and where you want classes built to. It's done in project properties dialog:

1. Right-click on your project in Eclipse, select Properties
2. Click on Java Build path on the left
3. Click source tab on the right
4. Click Add Folder button and add your source folder (`/WEB-INF/src` or wherever you moved it to)
5. Ensure **Allow output folders for source folders** is checked below
6. Under newly added source path select output folder and point it to `/WEB-INF/classes` or other location of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. I move everything to /src and followed the steps above and Eclipse is building my classes.  Unfortunately, the import resolution errors still exists.  Any reason why Eclipse can't find the .class file that were just built?

Comment: Hmm... did you refresh / rebuild the project? What happens if you try to import that class in another java class (and in another source location if you have more than one)? Does that work?

Comment: I refreshed/restarted Eclipse but the error persisted.  What finally worked was making the change in the JSP file and saving it again.  I guess that forced Eclipse to rescan the file and resolve correctly.  Thanks.