# Getting error while importing a class defined in the same project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, import

I went through the solution given [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540857/eclipse-wtp-the-import-cannot-be-resolved-for-error-in-a-jsp-file-for-a-c) , but it's not working in my case.That's why i am forced to ask my doubt.I have created a new folder `output` as suggested  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540857/eclipse-wtp-the-import-cannot-be-resolved-for-error-in-a-jsp-file-for-a-c)  and put all the `.class` files in this folder. And then to import a specific java class `ConnManager.java` which i have defined in the same project,i tried this  --

```
<%@ page import="output.ConnManager" %>
```

and even this  --

```
 <%@ page import="Summer.output.ConnManager" %>
```

Here output is the name of folder i created to store class files.And Summer is the name of the project.
But eclipse is giving `cannot be resolved error`.
How to remove this error ?

Comment: Project name is definitely not required while importing,i.e.you don't need to write 'Summer'. Need to check why first way is not working. Please provide your folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your *output* folder on Classpath. You can do so as follows:

```
Java Build Path > Under Libraries tab > Add Class Folder
```

Provide the *output* as class folder.

Now you will be able to import the file as `<%@ page import="output.ConnManager" %>`

[image: Java Build Path]

[image: Here you add your folder containing .class files]

Comment: @ Dhaval Simaria,this is what i did.I made a folder named "classfolder" inside "src" folder.And i put all class files in the classfolder and then i wrote-- `<%@ page import="src.classfolder.ConnManager" %>`  and then rebuild the project.But then also the error says `import classfolder cant be resolved`

Comment: but did you put that `classfolder` in your classpath? Attaching screen shot to my answer for your reference.

Comment: How to add it to classpath ?

Comment: I have just edited my answer to provide screenshots for reference.

Comment: Those steps i have already followed to add "classfolder" inside "src" folder.

Comment: It's not mandatory to put your folder inside src folder. Those screenshots are for reference. Only thing necessary is your folder should be included in the classpath. If you have done that then it's difficult to understand why it is not working.

Comment: It's done.Thanks.I just made a package and put ConnManager.java in it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you must use the package name of the class, not the file path.

Like :

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
```

Comment: That's the problem.Let's say my project name is "Summer" and inside it there is a folder "output" which contains all .class files related to project.Inside output i have "ConnManager.class". Now i want to import ConnManager inside other java class. Now how  to import ?

Comment: Like i said, use the package name...  
  
    `package java.util;  
    public interface List {...} `
  
Nothing to do with where the class is in  your project.

Comment: What is the package of your ConnManager class ?
is it your class or imported from external ?

Comment: I wrote that only  `<%@ page import="Summer.output.ConnManager" %>`.But it's not working.